# How to call reset on variety of inputs from OUTSIDE the form

Tags: javascript, html, input, reset

I have a form with various kinds of inputs, text, drop downs, radial buttons, sliders, and checkboxes. My "Reset" button is outside of the form (above the form). Is there a way to click the button and set all of the inputs back to default?

I have a Twitter Bootstrap accordion, with the reset button on the accordion header. The form is below inside of the accordion. I want to be able to clear the form whether the accordion is expanded or collapsed.

Example:

Accordion heading (Expanded)              Reset

input fields

Accordion heading (collapsed)             Reset

My reset is in my html like so:

```
<a id="icon-Reset" href="#form" class="btn-mini" type="reset"><i class="icon-refresh"  title="Reset" ></i></a>
```

and I was trying to do this in my javascript file:

```
#icon-Reset.click(function(){
$('#form').get(0).reset();
});
```

but I cannot get anything to work.

To be more clear, here is the top of the html that has the above html line in it:

```
<div id="side-bar-container">
<div id="sideBar">
    <div class="accordion" id="mainAccordion">
        <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-parent="#mainAccordion" data-target="#collapseOne"> <i
                    class="icon-chevron"></i>Accordion Heading1 
                </a>
                <a id="icon-Reset" href="#form" class="btn-mini" type="reset"><i class="icon-refresh"  title="Reset" ></i></a> 
            </div>
            <div id="collapse" class="accordion-body collapse in">
                <div class="accordion-inner scrollable">
                    <div id="Accordion1">
                        <form id="form"class="form-search form-horizontal">
                            <fieldset>
```

I am VERY new to Javascript, HTML, etc, so please be detailed...Thanks!!

Comment: read about jquery selectors, make an attempt, come back and post your code and ill help

Comment: Why is your Reset button outside the form? It can be positioned anywhere and still be inside the form

Comment: @DavidB, I've been reading and trying for the past 2 days. I have edited my question.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter, I have updated my question, but basically, I have a Twitter Bootstrap Accordion and I need the button on the accordion headers, not in the form inside of each accordion heading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach was correct, but you have to attach form reset action to the click event of your button. It can be any control, assuming it's a span with id "reset"

```
<span id="reset">Reset</span>
```

You can make clicking on it reset form with id "form" like this:

```
$('#reset').click(function() {

    $("#form")[0].reset();

})
```

This code attaches action to span's "onclick" event and inside of action gets the form and resets it. Here's a small demo - fill the form and then click Reset:

http://jsfiddle.net/29ewk/

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried this and it still does not work though, I added more of my html to my question. Does mine not work because its id is not reset? Or not a span? Or have I not linked my <a></a> correctly?

Comment: Actually yes, my sample code specifically used control with ID="reset". Can you as a test, replace that entire `<a id="icon-Reset" href="#form" class="btn-mini" type="reset"><i class="icon-refresh"  title="Reset" ></i></a>` line with `<span id="reset">Reset</span>` ? Also don't forget that you have to run that init code `$('#reset').click(function() {...` inside of `$(document ).ready(function() {...` call

Comment: I replaced all of my code with yours and it still didn't work...perhaps it is the rest of my program? Also, I do not understand what you mean with the $(document ).ready(function() {... call

Comment: If you don't already have `$(document).ready(function()..` in your JS code - see this updated demo, how the code should be applied: http://jsfiddle.net/29ewk/1/

Comment: Thank you for your help. My solution is as follows

$side-bar.find('#reset').on('click', function(){
   $side-bar.find('#form').trigger('reset');
  });

Comment: Gread find! I am glad this pointed you to the right directiion